# Windows folder path confusion

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, path

Up until now, I considered myself a decent programmer but now I am having doubts.

My folder structure is like below

```
Root
 |
 |--- Images (folder)
 |
 |--- Inc (folder)
 |     |
 |     |--- main.css
 |      --- autocomplete.css
 | 
 |--- start.aspx
```

I had my css file linked in start.aspx

```
<link href="/styles/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

But that was messing up the style... After long frustrating day, I just changed it to

```
<link href="styles/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

just to test one more useless possibility & it worked. It was working fine with / in start before & still works on production server...

I dont understand... Why suddenly css stopped working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't be so hard on yourself - stuff happens. :D

The leading "/" should resolve to the site root.

Using just "styles" would look for a styles folder in the current directory.

What browser were you using? Did the problem occur in one or every one?

Comment: but I was using the first link with / in the beginning since the start of the project. It never gave me any problem. I have that same code on production server & css works just fine... yesterday suddenly it just stopped.. I am using Firefox 3.6 .. same browser.. same code... that's why its so confusing

Comment: Hmm - it's a good question why suddenly it would stop working on you. Were you working locally or against a remote server? (Maybe something temporarily blocked that stylesheet between you and the server?) I've found sometimes flushing the DNS resolver cache clears issues like this.

Comment: You were absolutely right... When I was working on that part of code, I had this extra folder in root with same files. Just couple of days ago, I cleaned up everything and yesterday I was working on some other functionality when I saw that. Server still has that extra folder... I suck ~_~
But thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
 <link href="~/styles/autocomplete.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Comment: If you do use this, add a runat="server" attribute

Comment: Thanks for the option but I dont have path problem anymore. I just want to know why it would suddenly stop working with / in the beginning.